# Custom list permissions in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to figure out how to deal with custom list permissions.

I explain best with examples so I made up this scenario to explain my problem.

Say I have a `User` model, and the `User` has a `ForeignKey` to a `Bank`, a `Bank` can be opened (or not).

I have set the permission where the read requests for the `Bank` can only be permitted if `Bank` is opened,
Additionally, `User` object can be created by anybody (`Bank`, say, can only be created by admin user). So my permissions for `Bank` is something like this:

```
def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
    if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS
        return obj.opened
    return True
```

If I set my view to `queryset = Bank.objects.all()`

I go to `/banks`, I can still see banks that are closed (which is not what I wanted). If I go to `/banks/<pk>`, I will get a authentication required message (which is good).

So if I set my view to `queryset = Bank.objects.filter(opened=True)`

I go to `/banks`, and voila, only banks that are opened are listed.

Here is the tricky part,
If I go ahead and create a User, and since `Bank` is a `ForeignKey`, I can still see a list of all Banks available to choose from regardless of opened or not, in the API Browser.

How do I fix it so that only Banks that are opened is shown? Hopefully I'm clear enough with my example. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overwrite the `bank` field for your user serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bank = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Bank.objects.filter(opened=True))

    class Meta:
        model = User
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have been trying out your solution and it works for the problem I described above.